# problem in displaying string .the string fields are shown empty

Tags: c++, string

In display function all details are properly getting displayed except name which is given in string format. why is that strings sometimes don't get properly displayed?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct student{
    string n;
    int r;
    
    //taking details in
void details(){
       student s;
    cout<<"enter name of student"<<endl;
    cin >>s.n;
    cout<<"enter roll no of student"<<endl;
    cin >>s.r;
    }

    //display details
    void display(){
        student s;
        cout<<"name of the student : "<<s.n<<endl;
        cout<<"roll no of the student : "<<s.r<<endl;
    }
};

 int main(){
        int x,i;
        cout<<"enter no. of students : "<<endl;
        cin>>i;    
        student s[10];
    
    for(x=0;x<i;x++) {
        s[x].details();
    }
    
    for(x=0;x<i;x++) {
        s[x].display();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Change `void details()` to `bool details()` and return the state of `cin`. In general, always test the result of an IO transaction so you can handle failure. This is especially important with user input because humans are notoriously unreliable input sources.

Comment: Recommendation: prefer to give variables descriptive names. Good naming makes code practically document itself, making reading and understanding the code easy. It's also a lot harder to accidentally introduce a hard-to-spot typo like replacing `r` with `n` that will still compile. If the identifier is a whole word, screwing up one letter usually results in a compiler error. Swapping `r` for `n` you may only be able to find the mistake at runtime and after wasting time debugging the program.

Comment: @Tanmai really take into consideration those two comments above^. He is very wise. It really makes the code more legible when giving descriptive names. It makes it easier on your life and others that read your code.

Answer (score 1):

`details()` creates a *temporay* object `student s;` and writes to it's values without modifying the instance it was called on. After the function ends this temporary object `s` is discarded and nothing changed. Likewise `display` prints the (empty) values of a default-constructed temporary object.

In `details()` You want to modify the *current instance*, pointed to by `this`:

```
void details(){
    cout<< "enter name of student"<<endl;
    cin >> this->n;
    cout<< "enter roll no of student"<<endl;
    cin >> this->r;
}
```

and likewise `display`() should print `this->n` and `this->r`.

---

Allthough `this` is not required here, I like to be explicit about it.